# Iterate through nearest 3 dimensional vectors

Tags: arrays, loops, vector, nearest-neighbor

I have a 3 Dimensional array, like int[256][256][256]. Now I have a specific point in this array like 182, 12, 194. I need to iterate over the nearest neighbors sorted by euclidian distance to this point. For example:

with 182, 12, 194 it would iterate like:

- 182, 12, 194 +[0, 0, 0]
- 183, 12, 194 +[1, 0, 0]
- 182, 13, 194 +[0, 1, 0]
- 182, 12, 195 +[0, 0, 1]
- 181, 12, 194 +[-1, 0, 0]
- 182, 11, 194 +[0, -1, 0]
- 182, 12, 193 +[0, 0, -1]
- 183, 13, 194 +[1, 1, 0]
- 183, 12, 195 +[1, 0, 1]
- 182, 13, 195 +[0, 1, 1]

and so on.

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: So the point is considered to be its own neighbor?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I haven't tried anyhting yet, because I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @ScottHunter Yes the point itself is considered at its nearest neighbor, cause of the distance of 0 to itself

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 3 dimensions, then you can do it with 3 nested loops:

```
void iterate(int x, int y, int z) {
    int r = 1;
    for (int dx=-r; dx<=r; dx++) {
        for (int dy=-r; dy<=r; dy++) {
            for (int dz=-r; dz<=r; dz++) {
                array[x+dx][y+dy][z+dz] = ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(the `r` stands for the "radius", which is 1 for the case that you sketched).

For higher (or a variable number of) dimensions, some more sophisticated solution will be necessary.

Comment: Note that this does not properly handle cases where the point is at an edge (that is, x, y or z is either 0 or 255).

Comment: This is what I am currently doing, but my problem is that I need the checked points sorted by distance to the origin.

Comment: @ScottHunter Sure, I assumed that the question was mainly about the iteration. For bounds checks, it might be helpful to know the *language* in which this should be written.

Comment: @th3falc0n What distance measure? Euclidean, Manhattan, Chebyshev? Or do you simply want to build "3-dimensional "shells"" around the center point?

Comment: @Marco13 Euclidian distance is what I mean

Comment: @th3falc0n I'm pretty sure that you do NOT mean the euclidean distance, but I'll wait with further attempts to answer this question until either the question is made more clear and precise (and so on) or others have tried to answer it and received comments containing the information that should have been contained in the question right from the beginning.

Comment: @Marco13 I am pretty sure that I mean the euclidian distance, and I am also pretty sure, that I don't know how I can provide more information, because I think I can't clearify anymore after my 2 edits to the question.

Comment: So then: The easiest way to achieve this is to create a list of coordinate triplets `(x,y,z)`, put them into a list, and sort them based on their distance to the center point. This will not be very efficient, but easy.